# How can I add Seconds to my "timepicker"?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery-UI datepicker in this way:

```
var datepickerOpts = {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showWeek: true,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                        if (($("#BeginTime").val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#BeginTime").timeEntry("setTime", new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
                        }
                        $("#BeginTime").focus();
                    }
}

$("#BeginDate").datepicker(datepickerOpts);
```

The related [cs]html is:

```
<tr id="trBeginDate">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BeginDate)
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BeginDate, new {alt = "date-us", style = "width: 109px;"})
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BeginTime)
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BeginTime, new {style = "width: 109px;"})
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I want to show as a default value in the BeginTime textbox is "00:00:00", not just "00:00" as I get:

[image]

Actually, "00:00" is probably okay for the default begin time of midnight, but I need the default end time to be "23:59:59" not what it is now ("23:59") because that way practically an entire minute is potentially lost (from "23:59:01" to "23:59:59"). And so, "00:00" should be "00:00:00" to have a consistent format with "23:59:59").

Anyway, I tried this, but it doesn't work at all (nothing is added to the BeginTime textbox):

```
. . .
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                        if (($("#BeginTime").val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#BeginTime").text("00:00:00");
. . .
```

nor did this:

```
. . .
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                        if (($("#BeginTime").val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#BeginTime").text.val("00:00:00");
. . .
```

So how can I set the BeginTime value to "00:00:00"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the $.timeEntry() [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html), under the 'formats' tab is how to set different default formats. Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991020/why-is-my-second-timepicker-not-being-populated) here is how you would set seconds and a 24 hour clock:

```
// Start Date / Time
var beginDatepickerOpts = {
    ...
}
$('#BeginTime').timeEntry({
    showSeconds: true,
    show24Hours: true
});
$("#BeginDate").datepicker(beginDatepickerOpts);

// End Date / Time
var endDatepickerOpts = {
    ...
}
$('#EndTime').timeEntry({
    showSeconds: true,
    show24Hours: true
});
$("#EndDate").datepicker(endDatepickerOpts);
```

**EXAMPLE**

JSFiddle Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrCGa/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the link and you will get the required stuff.
http://www.avisbra.it/wp-content/plugins/lbwp_book/js/jquery/plugin/timepicker/

Comment: -1 Considering it is as simple as setting an option value to enable using the default jQuery datepicker, I don't think getting an additional plugin is an applicable answer.